# Does 2FA Help Prevent Unauthorized Access in Phishing Attacks?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, phishing

## Given

1. Attacker is targeting a user of `bank.com`.
2. `bank.com` uses SMS or Google Authenticator 2FA, where the user enters the 2FA code into a form.

## Scenario

1. Attacker registers domain name `baank.com`
2. Attacker creates a web page that scrapes the login page of `bank.com` and presents it from the domain `baank.com` (or working as a MITM proxy to send user supplied details back to `bank.com` if needed).
3. Attacker sends a phishing email to the user getting them to log in to `baank.com` instead of `bank.com`.
4. User fills in their username, password, and 2FA (as per usual).
5. Attacker now has the users credentials as well the 2FA that the user supplied.
6. Attacker immediately (maybe through a script) logs in to the bank account since he has the username, pass, and 2FA.

## Question

Am I missing something or does user-entered 2FA not help in this scenario?

Comment: Minor point: the 2FA step usually happens after credentials are validated. So the attacker gets the valid credentials first.

Comment: This kind of attack has been around a bit: https://www.zdnet.com/article/new-tool-automates-phishing-attacks-that-bypass-2fa/ https://blog.knowbe4.com/new-phishing-attacks-make-2fa-useless If I recall correctly, some hardware tokens have the ability to verify the URL before supplying a code.

Comment: This is why yubikey/U2F/Fido is the only real solution

Answer (score 21, accepted):

2FA **alone** does not help in this scenario. If the 2FA input screen on `bank.com` does not have other protections, like TLS, pinning/HSTS, MITM protection, and/or verify the client or detect login anomalies, then there is a vulnerability.

This is a case where an integrated password manager in the browser can help the end-user, by not providing the credentials to begin with.

Other types of 2FA, besides user-entered codes, offer greater protection.

Comment: quick question about password managers, off topic a little bit but connected to this 2FA question, how would they be able to know if the dns entry was altered in the hosts file? is there something the logs ip as well as dns entry and lets you know once it changes?

Comment: checking against IP would not be practical since IPs can change or services can use a pool of IPs

Comment: U2F protects against phishing by mixing the hash of the root domain into encrypted answer. It uses public key encryption, which prevents the need to share the secret, unlike TOTP. Since Google switched their 100,000+ employees to U2F security keys many years ago, they haven't had a single successful phishing attack against them. And they're a big target.

Comment: @Bengie that's why I've tried to be very clear about "user-entered" 2FA in the question. Other types of 2FA don't have the same problems.

Comment: @Coderxyz If the user has compromized your computer that completely to alter a protected hosts file, you are probably out of luck.  No need to use 2FA at all or redirect the user, simply steal the auth once the user logs into their bank, or generate requests using the user's own browser with the auth.  Besides compromising the host file though they would have to forge an SSL certificate to validate the domain if they don't have complete control of the browser or add their own root cert to the user's certificate store.  But again there would be more transparent means at that level.

Comment: Whilst not preventing an attack, if combined with rate limits, 2FA could reduce the impact of a phishing attack, as the rate limits would limit what the attacker could do with the acquired session, whilst 2FA would prevent the attacker from generating new sessions.

Comment: My bank asks for a TOTP code every time I make a transaction (which is incredibly annoying, I wish it was HOTP). If I log in just to check my balance, there's no way for the attacker to send himself money unless he can trick me into entering the code a second time.

Comment: @Fax sure, but the threat scenario in the question is about logging in, not subsequent actions.

Comment: @schroeder Indeed, it was not intended as criticism. I just thought it was worth noting that logging in to an account protected with 2FA without having the 2nd factor will typically not give you full control over that account.

Comment: @Fax I've actually never used a site that asks for 2FA on every transaction like your bank does. With sites that only ask for 2FA once when logging in but not for the rest of the session (which is typical in my experience), if you manage to log in then you probably do have full control over the account, or nearly so. (Of course it varies depending on the details of how the site handles authentication.)

Comment: I don't get how TLS and pinning affect the outcome. The victim is interacting only with the phishing page, it is the criminal that uses the real site. Unless with TLS and/or MITM protection you meant a client certificate or equivalent.

Comment: @DavidZ I think most sites ask for 2FA when changing your log-in credentials, particularly when changing 2FA method. At least Google does, I just checked.

Answer (score 14):

Security keys like yubikey, titankey, nitrokey, and solokey use the U2F protocol, which is immune to phishing by mixing the domain into the nonce. In order for this to happen, the attacker would have to have control of the domain. And if you're talking about a browser, they are configured to also require the page to be a valid HTTPS connection. Meaning the attacker would also have to have control of the site's private certificate.

At this point the attacker already has control of everything.

I want to say it's something like this

response = secretkey_encrypt(HMAC(CHALLENGE, SHA256(base domain)))

Comment: how does the U2F get the domain? I was under the impression they were basically a preprogrammed keyboard and could only send info and not receive it.

Comment: The browser needs to incorporate the protocol.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to use a client side certificate?

Answer (score 6):

**It reduces the window in which an attack may be carried**

Consider the case where the connection does **not** have 2FA, only user and password. The victim provided his bank credentials and doesn't even realize it was a phishing after the fact. The attacker can later use them to log in as the user and empty the account. Perhaps during the night, when the user is more likely not to notice. Or leverage that access through several days to overcome the daily transfer limit. Or three months later, when he completely forgot about that phishing, those credentials could have been sold to someone else that then uses it for money laundering.

As you rightly note, the use of 2FA does not prevent that as a result of a phishing, an attacker logged into the account *at that same time*. The previous scenarios are no longer feasible. The attack must be carried out at the time the user is entering their credentials. Even a minute later, the second factor will have expired. It does not completely prevent the attacker logging in (for that you would need a U2F/FIDO/WebAuthn device, also verifying the **site** you log into) but it does raise the effort required.

Plus, when using SMS, some sites actually describe the action that is going to be performed, so such description *may* serve as an additional layer of defense ("The page states it needs my code to give me a free gift, but the SMS says it will authorize a transfer of several thousand dollars?" ).

On the other hand, some scenarios *are* solved by the use of a second factor, such as a shoulder-surfer discovering the credentials or the concern that the password could be bruteforced.

Answer (score 4):

Going into incorrect URLs would of course pose a risk even with 2FA. You correctly identified that. 2FA is aimed more towards leaked passwords for the correct URL. There will always be risks where human naivety is concerned, so providing people check the URLs, in most scenarios 2FA does help.

Answer (score 0):

Now what your are missing out is that when the victim input his/her login details using your phishing page the user will not receive any 2FA code unless you have a background listener that does the login on the real bank site using the details supplied by the victim so that the victim can supply the 2FA code received immediately and then the listener service uses the supplied 2FA to complete the login process.

this is one of the reason why it is recommended to upgrade from 2FA to authenticator app.

see the article below for more details about authentication.

[SMS-based two-factor authentication is not safe — consider these alternative 2FA methods instead](https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/2fa-practical-guide/24219/)

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is SMS or a TOPT app. The same process applies if it is user-supplied. TOTP just adds a 30 second timer. Yes, the phishing page would need to enter the creds on the legitimate page, but that is possible to code. As I mention, though, the login pages would need to be designed to look for anomalies to prevent this from happening. If they don't then this attack is trivial.

Comment: yea, I kinda envisioned using a proxy server really that would forward all user request to the web server as well, I added this to my question for clarity, thanks.

Comment: @schroeder of course it might still works on other forms authentication thanks for your correction.